# In Ruby on Rails, how to render JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, view, render

I tried the following to respond to AJAX and it works (in HAML):

```
  - response.content_type = "application/json"
  = render :text => array_data.to_json
```

but

```
  - response.content_type = "application/json"
  = render :json => array_data.to_json
```

doesn't work.  I thought I could use

```
  = render :text => array_data.to_json
```

instead of the first 2 lines at the top?

Answer (score 2):

```
= render :json => @object
```

(u don't need to use .to_json method)

Comment: I also tried `= render :json => {:data => arrayData}` and see that in Firebug, the Response data portion is empty as well.

Comment: @retro, both cases, the Firebug shows an empty respond data portion.  Response header say `Content-length` is 1

Comment: Why you're rendering your json in view ?

Comment: Because there is a partial that return a single entry, and I need to loop through an array and concat the partial results to form 1 column, and loop 3 times to get 3 columns, and return it as a JSON data for Ajax

Comment: What if my json object is not restful? What if it's not even a variable, but a method defined somewhere else like the application controller?

Comment: gwho: use @object.to_json