# In Ruby on Rails, why "render :json => array_data" shows nothing, but "render :text => array_data.to_json" shows the data array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In Ruby on Rails, why

```
render :json => array_data
```

shows nothing (as seen in Firebug, the GET in the console), but

```
render :text => array_data.to_json
```

shows the data array?

This is related to [In Ruby on Rails, how to render JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367246/in-ruby-on-rails-how-to-render-json)